How to safely remove LVM crash volume?
In an Oracle Linux 9 VM I just created on Azure, I see that the basic setup has a LVM root filesystem, with the root VG separated in

22GB root LV
10GB crash LV

I was wondering, what might be the impact of removing the crash LV and re-assigning its 10GB to the root LV, supposing that I also update the fstab file to not try to mount that filesystem anymore, and how to properly remove it?
To further clarify based on comment from Chris Davies, I do not think this is a duplicate of Resize a LVM partition on linux disk of Azure, as that question is about allocating the available extra space to the root LV.
Instead, in this question, I'd like to know how I can safely remove the crash LV to recover some space, which then can be assigned to the root LV following that procedure.

This question is similar to: Resize a LVM partition on linux disk of Azure. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks for your input, I have clarified why I do not think it is a duplicate; said very briefly, my question is about removing, not adding, and also possibly how to do so "safely" (as in, not breaking the system).

"I was wondering, what might be the impact of removing the crash LV and re-assigning its 10GB to the root LV" and "that [duplicate] question is about allocating the available extra space to the root LV_2" - still seems the same to me..?

The difference is that I know how to add available space to a LV, but I do not know how to cleanly REMOVE one, and what impact might have removing this specific LV.
